# Could anyone tell me how to find optimal conditions in more details from here?

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

\begin{align*}
\max Y&=R_1X_1+R_{2}X_{2}+R_3X_3+R_4X_4+R_5X_5+R_6X_6,\\
\text{s.t}:&F_1(X_1,X_{2}, \dots, X_{6})=X_1+X_3+X_5-1\le 0,\\
&F_2(X_1,X_{2}, \dots, X_{6})=X_2+X_4+X_6-1\le 0,\\
&F_3(X_1,X_{2}, \dots, X_{6})=R_1X_1+R_{2}X_{2}-C_1\le 0,\\
&F_4(X_1,X_{2}, \dots, X_{6})=R_3X_3+R_4X_4-C_2\le 0,\\
&F_5(X_1,X_{2}, \dots, X_{6})=R_5X_5+R_{6}X_{6}-C_3\le 0,\\
X_i\in \mathbb R \forall i=1,2,\dots, 6.
\end{align*}
If $y^{\star}\in \mathbb R^6$ is the optimal point, and if $\mu_1,\dots, \mu_5\in \mathbb R$ are Lagrange multipliers then it is easy to see from the dual feasibility condition:
\begin{align}
&\nabla Y(y^{\star})-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{5}\mu_i \nabla F_i(y^{\star})=0 \text{ we get }\\
&R_1-\mu_1-\mu_3R_1=0\\
&R_2-\mu_2-\mu_3R_2=0\\
&R_3-\mu_1-\mu_4R_3=0\\
&R_4-\mu_2-\mu_4R_4=0\\
&R_5-\mu_1-\mu_5R_5=0\\
&R_6-\mu_2-\mu_5R_6=0\\
&\mu_1,\mu_2,\dots, \mu_5\ge 0.
\end{align}
primal feasibility:
\begin{align}
F_i(y^{\star})&\le 0\quad \forall i=1,2,\dots,5.
\end{align}
complementary slackness:
\begin{align}
\mu_i F_i(y^{\star})=0 \quad \forall i=1,2,\dots, 5.
\end{align}

Could anyone tell me how to write Dual of the above problem and find optimal conditions in more detail from here? So far have I done the correct steps? Thank you for helping. What are dual variables here? How to find KKT?

Comment: Does [this](https://mat.uab.cat/~alseda/MasterOpt/16-kkt.pdf) help ?

Comment: I'd start reading from p.1 and there are only 26 slides - that's not a lot !.